# Correct way to display 404 page in PHP?

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404

So currently when a user loads a page that doesn't exist, or something goes wrong - I redirect users to a 404 page using `header` in PHP:

```
header('Location: www.website.com/404'); //This is simplified intentionally
```

This page displays a 404 icon with a link back to the homepage, and some other information

Recently in Google Webmaster tools I've been getting a few messages that I'm not returning a 404 page correctly.

Should I be returning `http_response_code` when displaying the 404 page? Or should I be handling 404 differently?

Comment: don't do that. the redirect sends the browser to a new page, which will then receive a `200 OK` response. You need to output an actual 404 status code as part of your error page. so instead of redirecting, you do `header('http/1.1 404 not found'); echo 'not found'` directly.

Comment: you should use .htaccess, or redirect the page to 301 or 302 redirection

Answer (score 2):

You can't use this. There can be only **one** status code. And in case of redirect it will be 301, **not 404**.

So you should make it

```
http_response_code(404);
include '404.html'; // or whatever
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

htaccess 404 Error Code

Once you have your 404 page setup, all you need to do is send visitors of incorrect url’s to this page. To do this just add the following line to your .htaccess file :

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Most often, the .htaccess file will be in the home root public_html folder on your server. This can change, for an example if you run you site or blog out of a specific folder within the public_html.

Alternately, You can place the 404 error template anywhere you want in a folder. For example you could place all error messages in a folder called errormessages refererring the 404 error to the url of the page.

ErrorDocument 404 /errormessages/404.php

That’s all there is to it.

Now when a visitor views an incorrect url on your site they will see your custom 404 error message.Its well explained [here.](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/)

Answer (score 0):

any internet crawler/spider or tools have 404 status code as not found so you better output the status code so the page will be known for what it is

you can do that by outputting a raw header like this

```
<?php
if(!authorized){
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
echo "*OUTPUT*";
?>
```

but this alone causes a security issue because the rest of the pages output is being output and is still executed:

```
$ curl http://localhost/stackoverflow/404.php
*OUTPUT*
```

so you should exit after redirecting, so the code will be like this:

```
<?php
if(!authorized){
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  exit;
}
echo "*OUTPUT*";
?>
```

and now it will stop executing after the redirect

```
$ curl http://localhost/stackoverflow/404.php
$
```

and for more safety use htaccess.